# network interface (onboard wired) is showed p5p1 instead eth0

Tags: networking, configuration

I've running Ubuntu 13.04 on my computer and it's ok.
But some softwares like media servers don't work well. They search network interface eth0 and Ubuntu 13.04 named it p5p1. So my media server doesn't work.

How can I change Ubuntu's network config file?

Comment: Just an FYI.  Ubuntu did not name it p5p1.  Asus did or your motherboard.  For some very strange reason some MB makers decided to change the way their eth ports talk to the system.  We have the same situation at the school where I work.

Answer (score 5):

In ubuntu 14.04, all I did was this:

1. Modify `/etc/default/grub` and add:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0"
   ```
2. Then force the create of a new `grub.cfg`file

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```
3. Then reboot the system

Comment: Wow this worked for me!!! I have been looking for an answer like this forever.  Where can I find more information about this command and how it works?

Answer (score 3):

The predictable network interface names were introduced with udev-197 and are now standard on many Linux distribution. Although it's possible to go back to the old naming scheme, I'd expect that this causes more troubles than it solves. You can nevertheless try to follow one of the hints on how to go back to unpredictable network interface names given in the following article:

http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/

I don't have 13.04 installed, but I guess that the udev version there is new enough so the kernel command line parameter net.ifnames=0 should work and is probably the most easy solution.

Comment: Those unpredictable "predictable network interface names" should have been avoided in first place! They have caused so much irritation and harm to so many average joe Linux users. I've disabled these on ALL of my Linux systems with the boot option "net.ifnames=0" since this problem popped up at first and never looked back.